# how to make header sticky using css

Tags: html, css

I want to make a sticky header in my website. I am trying following CSS but when I use the CSS below, My logo gets zoomed out when viewed on a mobile device.

URL of the website : http://gomodemo.se/port73/

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){

    header{
        position: fixed !important;
        top: 0px;
    }

});
```

I do not have any issue on the desktop but on a mobile device, the logo gets zoom out.When I click on hamburger menu in the mobile device the logo gets zoom out. Not only logo my header section gets zoom out. Please help me to resolve the issue. Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by zooming out?

Comment: Screenshot? What do you mean by "Zooming out" - could you be a bit more descriptive?  Feel free to attach a screenshot.

Comment: hi @Rashmi using media query you can also chage size of your logo...

Comment: Use percentage instead of pixels

Comment: @Jeremy Iglehart: When i click on hamburger menu in the mobile device the logo gets zoom out. Not only logo my header section gets zoom out.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
.logo img {
    height: 88px;
    width: 72%;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> When styling your logo, be sure to use percentage instead of pixels.

When using pixels, you are setting the position and size of your logo native to your resolution - causing it to look zoomed when viewed from a different resolution (because your mobile device might have a higher resolution). If someone who has a higher resolution views your website, there is an area which you have not covered because of the additional pixels on the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use height value in Percentage.
And don't use important unless  you don't have another options.

You can use below code:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1200px) { 
.logo img {
    margin-top: -10%;
    max-height: 50%;
     }
}
```

Comment: If you provide fiddle then i can explain you more clearly, If required.